# How do i create relationships for existing nodes by importing csv file in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

lets say i have created  [a],[b],[c],[d] nodes in neo4j. how to create relationships among those nodes by importing csv data.

```
csv data:

id,fromNode,toNode,typeOfRelation
1,a,b,KNOWs
2,b,c,FOLLOWS
3,d,a,KNOWS
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this way if your Nodes are in the Graph already.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Label(name);

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///<PathToYourCSV>" as input
MATCH (from:Label  {name: input.fromNode}), (to:Label {name: input.toNode})
CREATE (from)-[:RELATION { type: input.typeOfRelation }]->(to);
```

To query it, you can use

```
MATCH (n:Label {name: 'b'}), 
(n)-[rel:RELATION]->(follower)
where rel.type = 'FOLLOWS'
return n, follower
```

Patrick