# How to import relationships between nodes of the same label from a csv file in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship, graph-databases

I have two separate csv files that I need to import into my neo4j database. The first file contains all the nodes that I wish to import. The information is classified as follows:

```
                             id, Name 

                              1, Earth science
```

To import it, I successfully used the following code:

> LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Node_test.csv' AS line
>
> CREATE (:Discipline { id: toInt(line.id), name: line.Name})

Now, I want to import my relationship file and create all the relationship between the nodes I just imported. The information in the relationship.csv file is classified as follows:

```
                 RelationshipID, parentID, relationship_type, childID

                              1, 2, IS_A_PARENT_DISCIPLINE_OF, 5
```

To import it, I used the following code, without success :

> USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
> LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///relationship_test.csv" AS csvLine
>
> MATCH (DParent:Discipline { id: toInt(csvLine.parentID)}),(DChild:Discipline { id: toInt(csvLine.childID)})
>
> CREATE (DParent)-[:IS_A_PARENT_DISCIPLINE_OF { id:toInt(csvLine.RelationshipID) } ]->(DChild)

Note: The result doesn't show any errors, it just returned no changes, no rows.

Please see the links below for other documentations I found regarding the subject; I have not found any documentation describing how to import csv files in order to create relationships between nodes of the same Label.

http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.0-M01/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html

[How do i create relationships for existing nodes by importing csv file in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279278/how-do-i-create-relationships-for-existing-nodes-by-importing-csv-file-in-neo4j)

[Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0: Can't Create Relationship Between Nodes with the Same Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418226/spring-data-neo4j-4-0-0-cant-create-relationship-between-nodes-with-the-same-l)

Comment: Does your first file actually contain rows for id values 2 and 5?

Comment: Yes. And I am pretty sure it's not missing ids in the first file because I would get an error message. Isn't?

Comment: The failure to find a match is not treated as an error.

Comment: Ok I will make a second check. Thanks!

Comment: The relationship file has been verified. This is not the issue. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the content of the import.cypher file that you need to create and run in the neo4j-shell to import the data...

Important thing is when matching and trying to create relationships you need to use the MERGE command

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:data/node.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Discipline{disciplineId: toInt(row.id), name: row.Name});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:data/rels.csv" AS row
MATCH (parent:Discipline{disciplineId: toInt(row.parentID)})
MATCH (child:Discipline {disciplineId: toInt(row.childID)})
MERGE (parent)-[:IS_PARENT_DISCIPLINE_OF]->(child);
```