# Neo4J Create Relationships in Cypher returns no changes, no rows

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, relationships

I have a CSV dataset through which I'm trying to build relationships between two node types(`Comment` and `Person`) that already exist in my database.

This is the database information -

[image]

This is the csv file of the current relationship `comment_hasCreator_person` that I'm trying to build -
[image]

The problem is - no matter which Cypher query I try, all of them returns the same thing - "no changes, no rows".

Here are the different variations of the query I've tried -

This is the first query -

```
// comment_hasCreator_person_0_0.csv
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qb4occggixmaz9g/comment_hasCreator_person_0_0.csv" AS line
MATCH (comment:Comment { id: toInt(line.Comment.id)}),(person:Person { id: toInt(line.Person.id)})
CREATE (comment)-[:hasCreator]->(person)
```

I assumed this might have not worked because my CSV headers were initially named `Comment.id` and `Person.id`. So I removed the `.` and tried out the query, with the same result -

```
// comment_hasCreator_person_0_0.csv
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qb4occggixmaz9g/comment_hasCreator_person_0_0.csv" AS line
MATCH (comment:Comment { id: toInt(line.Commentid)}),(person:Person { id: toInt(line.Personid)})
CREATE (comment)-[:hasCreator]->(person)
```

When that didn't work, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439249/how-to-import-relationships-between-nodes-of-the-same-label-from-a-csv-file-in-n) and tried using `MERGE` instead of `CREATE`, even though it shouldn't make a difference because the relationships didn't exist in the first place -

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://www.dropbox.com/s/qb4occggixmaz9g/comment_hasCreator_person_0_0.csv?dl=0" AS line
MATCH (comment:Comment { id: toInt(line.Commentid)}),(person:Person { id: toInt(line.Personid)})
MERGE (comment)-[r:hasCreator]->(person)
RETURN comment,r, person
```

This query just returned "no rows".

I also tried a variation of the query where I didn't use the `toInt()` function, but that didn't make any difference.

To ensure the nodes exist, I selected random cell values from the CSV file and used a `MATCH` clause to ensure the corresponding `Comment` and `Person` nodes exist in the database, and I did find all the nodes.

As the last step, I decided to create a relationship manually between the first row values from the CSV file -

```
MATCH (c:Comment{id:1236950581249}), (p:Person{id:10995116284808})
CREATE (c)-[r:hasCreator]->(p)
RETURN c,r,p
```

and this worked just fine -

[image]

I'm totally clueless as to why the relationships won't get created when I import it from the CSV file. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in yout CSV file. The field terminator character used in it is "|" and not the default ",". You can edit your CSV file and chenge the field terminator character to "," or use the option [FIELDTERMINATOR](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#csv-file-format) available in the `LOAD CSV`.

Try editing your query to something like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://www.dropbox.com/s/qb4occggixmaz9g/comment_hasCreator_person_0_0.csv?dl=0" AS line
FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
MATCH (comment:Comment { id: toInt(line.Commentid)}),(person:Person { id: toInt(line.Personid)})
MERGE (comment)-[r:hasCreator]->(person)
RETURN comment,r, person
```

Comment: Thank You so much, I don't know why I completely overlooked the `|`. Especially since I used `fieldterminator` during creation of my nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the field terminator here as it is `|` in your case, instead of `;`.

You can try this out:

`USING PERIODIC COMMIT
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "filename" AS LINE FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
    MERGE (comment:Comment { id: toInt(LINE.Commentid)})
    MERGE (person:Person { id: toInt(line.Personid)})
    MERGE (comment) - [r:has_creator] -> (person)
    RETURN comment,r,person`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this kind of error may be white spaces in CSV file. If line in CSV looks like:

```
2a9b40bc-78f0-4e79-9b2b-441108883448, Pink node - 2, 2, pink
```

then index 1 for results will be: ' Pink node - 2' (notice space at beginning), not: 'Pink node - 2'. Editing csv files or using trim() function would be the solution here:

```
...
WHERE a.id = trim(line[0]) AND b.id = trim(line[1]) 
...
```